# simple 1D example showing convolution vs correlation to test commutative/associative property

Tags: correlation, convolution, proof, associative

So I've known this fact that convolution has commutative/associative property while correlation does not but never really written out a simple example to test this out. (proofs in equation forms exist out there)

I was just trying this simple example:

```
Image : [1 0 -1 0 1 0 1 1]
A kernel = [-1 0 1]
B kernel = [-1 0 1]
```

Using convolution, I * (A * B) should equal (I * A) * B, but when I tried this they were not equal.. which confused me a lot. would anyone be able to help out? maybe I made a human error in doing computation.. but they should be equal right? (assuming borders are treated as 0s)

And using correlation, the same should not be equal as I understand.. which they dont, but then, my convolution did not either so lol (but it should!)

Any help would be appreciated.

also,
A*B (convolution) would be [0 -2 0] right?
and AxB (cross correlation) would be [0 2 0]?

Answer (score 0):

The convolution operator is commutative. So, you are right that `I*(A*B)` should be equal to `(I*A)*B`. Let's convert this to matrix formation first. Convolution by kernel A can be translated to multiplication by the following convolution matrix, C:

```
C=
 [-1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0 -1  0  1  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0 -1  0  1  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0 -1  0  1  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0 -1  0  1  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0 -1  0  1]
 [ 1  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0]
 [ 0  1  0  0  0  0  0 -1]
```

We have taken the kernel [-1 0 1] and zero-padded it by 5 zeros on first row. Then, each row below is a cyclic shift by 1 position to the right of the preceding row.
So, if we want to compute the convolution of kernel A with I:

```
I = [1 0 -1 0 1 0 1 1]
```

We simply compute the matrix-vector multiplication:

```
C*I^T
```

(where I^T is the transposed vector).

Following the above formulation, we obtain:

```
I*(A*B) = (C*C)*I^T
```

Computing C*C you get the following matrix:

```
C^2=
 [ 1  0 -2  0  1  0  0  0]
 [ 0  1  0 -2  0  1  0  0]
 [ 0  0  1  0 -2  0  1  0]
 [ 0  0  0  1  0 -2  0  1]
 [ 1  0  0  0  1  0 -2  0]
 [ 0  1  0  0  0  1  0 -2]
 [-2  0  1  0  0  0  1  0]
 [ 0 -2  0  1  0  0  0  1]
```

and:

```
I*(A*B) = (C*C)*I^T = 
 [ 4]
 [ 0]
 [-2]
 [ 1]
 [ 0]
 [-2]
 [-2]
 [ 1]
```

whereas `(I*A)*B` is in matrix formulation `C*(C*I^T)` which is equal to `I*(A*B)=(C*C)*I^T` from matrix associativity.

You can validate this result by running the following numpy code:

```
import numpy as np
C = [[-1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]]
for k in range(7):
    C.append(np.roll(C[0],k+1))
C = np.array(C)
#print(C)
I = np.transpose(np.array([[1,0,-1,0,1,0,1,1]]))

print(f'C=\n{C}\n')
print(f'C^2=\n{C@C}\n')

print(f'(C*C)*I=\n{(C@C)@I}\n')
print(f' C*(C*I)=\n{C@(C@I)}\n')
```

The result of running the above code is:

```
C=
[[-1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0 -1  0  1  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0 -1  0  1  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0 -1  0  1  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0 -1  0  1  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0 -1  0  1]
 [ 1  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0]
 [ 0  1  0  0  0  0  0 -1]]

C^2=
[[ 1  0 -2  0  1  0  0  0]
 [ 0  1  0 -2  0  1  0  0]
 [ 0  0  1  0 -2  0  1  0]
 [ 0  0  0  1  0 -2  0  1]
 [ 1  0  0  0  1  0 -2  0]
 [ 0  1  0  0  0  1  0 -2]
 [-2  0  1  0  0  0  1  0]
 [ 0 -2  0  1  0  0  0  1]]

(C*C)*I=
[[ 4]
 [ 0]
 [-2]
 [ 1]
 [ 0]
 [-2]
 [-2]
 [ 1]]

 C*(C*I)=
[[ 4]
 [ 0]
 [-2]
 [ 1]
 [ 0]
 [-2]
 [-2]
 [ 1]]
```

So you can see that the same result is obtained.

Note that `A*B` is not [0 -2 0] but [1  0 -2  0  1] because you take A=[-1 0 1] (zero pad it on both sides to it has 2 zeros on each side) and move it as a sliding window over B=[-1 0 1] so first you get: [-1*-1, 0*-1 + -1*0, -1*1 + 0*0 + 1*-1, 1*0 + 0*1, 1*1] = [1  0 -2  0  1]. The resulting convolution of 2 kernels of width n will be of length 2*n-1.